# Training multiple Keras models concurrently with MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing

I want to train multiple Keras models concurrently, using multiprocessing. And, I want to do so using many GPUs on one machine. This is actually part of a larger algorithm whereby each model will be trained using a different optimizer; but, for example sake, I have put together the following python code which exemplifies, roughly, what I'm trying to achieve.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing as mp
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Create a strategy for multi-GPU
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

# Define function to load and preprocess the data
def get_dataset():
    batch_size = 32
    num_val_samples = 10000

    # Return the MNIST dataset in the form of a `tf.data.Dataset`
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

    # Preprocess the data (these are Numpy arrays)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1).astype("float32") / 255
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1).astype("float32") / 255
    y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
    y_test = y_test.astype("float32")

    # Reserve num_val_samples samples for validation
    x_val = x_train[-num_val_samples:]
    y_val = y_train[-num_val_samples:]
    x_train = x_train[:-num_val_samples]
    y_train = y_train[:-num_val_samples]
    return (
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val)).batch(batch_size),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size),
    )

def train_model(num):
    print(num)

    # Open a strategy scope and create/compile the Keras model
    with strategy.scope():

      # AlexNet model
      model = keras.Sequential(
          [
              layers.Conv2D(96, 11, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
              layers.BatchNormalization(),
              layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2, padding='same'),
              layers.Conv2D(256, 5, 1, activation='relu', padding='same'),
              layers.BatchNormalization(),
              layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2, padding='same'),
              layers.Conv2D(384, 3, 1, activation='relu', padding='same'),
              layers.BatchNormalization(),
              layers.Conv2D(384, 3, 1, activation='relu', padding='same'),
              layers.BatchNormalization(),
              layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, activation='relu', padding='same'),
              layers.BatchNormalization(),
              layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2, padding='same'),
              layers.Flatten(),
              layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
              layers.Dropout(0.5),
              layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
              layers.Dropout(0.5),
              layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
          ])

      model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
        
    # Get the datasets
    train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()

    # Train the model
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset, use_multiprocessing=True)

    # Evaluate the model
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
        
    return (num, test_acc)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool()
    fitnesses = pool.map(train_model, [1, 2])
    print(fitnesses)
```

Currently the above example hangs after logging the following twice  (1 for each process, I assume): `F tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:147] Failed setting context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error`

My question is, is the approach I'm following reasonable (that is, using python's multiprocessing module and tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy to train multiple models concurrently and using many GPUs on one machine)? A lot of this is quite new to me so it's likely I may be missing something obvious. But, if the approach is reasonable, what causes the `CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED` and how can I fix it?